# Angular Child Element Animation Snapping on State Change

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, angular-animations

I have a parent and child element, each with separate animations. The animations share a state variable (so they perform their animations at the same time). If the state changes before the animations are complete, the child element snaps to its defined state styles instead of pausing/reversing the animation. The parent animation works as expected.

How do I make the child element smoothly pause/reverse without snapping on state change?

**StackBlitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-animation-snap-issue

**Animation Triggers & Markup:**

```js
trigger( 'childAnimation', [
  state( 'yes', style( {
    transform: 'scale( 2 ) translate3d( 0, 0, 0 )',
  } ) ),
  transition( '* => *', animate( '3s ease' ) ),
] ),

trigger( 'parentAnimation', [
  state( 'yes', style( {
    transform: 'translateY( 50% ) translateZ( 0 )',
  } ) ),
  transition( '* => *', [
    group( [
      query( '@*', animateChild() ),
      animate( '2s ease' ),
    ] ),
  ] ),
] ),
```

```html
<div id="parent" [@parentAnimation]="animateStuff">
  <div id="child" [@childAnimation]="animateStuff">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? If so, please post the solution if you can. Thanks!